# Graphical VHDL Component Editor

Tags: vhdl

In many of my VHDL designs I create a lot of low level components in HDL (which is fine). However, when I am ready to create multiple instantiations and link them together at the top-level, I find that the file ends up being rather large with tons of internal signals going between tons of component instantiations. It gets a little unwieldy and hard to follow.

Instead, I thought what might be easier to understand and faster to develop with is if there was a graphical tool to do the high level component linking. It would be able to parse my low level HDL files and determine the port inputs/outputs and create a block (or multiple instances of that block). I could then use my mouse to create connections between the blocks and give them a text label. When I am done, it would be able to auto-generate a VHDL file with all appropriate syntax for creating internal signals, component instantiations, port declarations, etc.

I tried experimenting with Xilinx Schematic Editor, but this thing was a beast and I did not have any luck.

Is there any tool out there like this? If it could even get me 90% of the way I'd be happy.

Comment: I don't know how many component instances are in a ton, but it sounds like you need to add some modularity to your design.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [www.sigasi.com](http://www.sigasi.com)

Sigasi has autocompletes to help you with the instantiations and quick-fixes to help you with the wiring. There is also a premium version that gives you a live, graphical block diagram view ([demo screencast](http://www.sigasi.com/screencast/block-diagram-view))